# Is there any rule when replacing apostrophe intead of some letters?

Tags: informal-language, apostrophe

In some English songs I found words like:

- *nothin'*
- *'em*
- *gon'*
- *'bout*

Is there any rule to make words likes that? Is they are formal? Is there any more such examples?

Comment: Suggested reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxed_pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few short forms that are an accepted part of informal English, and must be done correctly: for example

```
is not -> isn't
I am  -> I'm
we have ->we've
cannot -> can't
```

Other than these 'accepted' short forms, the apostrophe can used to write down other, less widely accepted, short forms. Often, there are also changes in pronunciation that accompany the shortening:

```
Nothing -> nuttin'
is not -> idn't
```

For this type of short form, there are no conventions: you just write down what you hear.